# Simple D3.js line chart with data that are values collect every hours

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm really a newbie on D3.js and I need to produce a simple line chart using values that are collected every hours

I'm trying to use this D3.js sample ...

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5

... and adapt it to my data that is something like this

```
6/28/2016-10:2:0,24.3
6/28/2016-9:2:0,23.2 
6/28/2016-8:2:0,22.2 
6/28/2016-7:2:0,21.5 
6/28/2016-6:2:0,21.2 
6/28/2016-5:2:0,20.8 
6/28/2016-4:2:0,21.6 
6/28/2016-3:2:0,21.6 
6/28/2016-2:2:0,22.0 
6/28/2016-1:2:0,22.4 
6/28/2016-0:2:0,23.3 
6/27/2016-23:2:0,25.0
6/27/2016-22:2:0,25.4
6/27/2016-21:2:0,27.0
```

where 6/28/2016-10:2:0 is the time (mm/dd/yyyy-hh:mm:sec) and 24.3 is the value I'd like to plot (note that I can modify this structure if needed ...)

How may I set the time format in my case, so how I've to modify the following lines?

```
// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

Are these the only lines that I've to modify to replicate the sample code with my data?

Any samples / suggestion?

Sorry for the entry-level question, I hope that after this I could move my next steps in more independent way!!!

Cesare

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the data in data.csv in example with your data should work. D3 will scale and plot the values on the graph by itself. If you want to change the x-scale and want to include time as well, you have to change the format specifier in the same line that you have mentioned from this line:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

To this line:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S").parse;
```

I have added the sample for your code, check this out: [line chart with date and time](http://plnkr.co/edit/oyAnXiAlJbnC93A7aVhD?p=preview).

[Here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format) are the list of format specifiers that you can use and here is the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95).